# Display some arrays and multidimensional arrays together

Tags: php

Here are the variables:

```
$ids = array_unique($_POST['id']);
$total_ids = count($ids);

$name = $_POST['name'];

$positions = $_POST['position'];
$total_positions = count($positions);
```

This is what the print_r shows:

```
[id] => Array ( 
    [0] => 3 
    [1] => 7 ) 

[name] => Array ( 
    [0] => George 
    [1] => Barack ) 

[position] => Array ( 
    [1] => Array ( 
        [0] => 01 
        [1] => 01 ) 
    [2] => Array ( 
        [0] => 01 
        [1] => 01 
        [2] => 01 ) )
```

This is the result which I would like to get on refresh/submit:

```
[id][0];
    [name][0];
        [position][1][0];[position][1][1]
[id][1];
    [name][1];
        [position][2][0];[position][2][1];[position][2][2]
```

To make the wanted result well clear:

```
User with [id][0] 
    is called [name][0] 
        and works at [position][1][0];[position][1][1]
BUT

User with [id][1]
    is called [name][1];
        and works at [position][2][0];[position][2][1];[position][2][2]
```

Please note that `[position]`s starts with `[1]`, not `[0]`.

**How could I display the arrays in the order I showed?**

Comment: That's a big mess of nested arrays, you'd be better refactoring your code into objects - at least, I didn't get what you want as final result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure I understand what you need, but to try to match the final-example of the output you displayed I came up with the following:

```
// iterate through each of the `$ids` as a "user"
foreach ($ids as $key => $value) {
    // output the user's ID
    echo 'User with ' . $value;
    if (isset($name[$key])) {
        // output the user's name
        echo ' is called ' . $name[$key];
    }
    if (isset($position[$key + 1])) {
        // output a ';'-delimited list of "positions"
        echo ' and works at ';
        $positions = '';
        // the `$positions` array starts with index 1, not 0
        foreach ($position[$key + 1] as $pos) {
            $positions .= (($positions != '') ? ';' : '') . $pos;
        }
        echo $positions;
    }
    echo '<br />';
}
```

This will give output similar to:

> User with 1 is called Bill and works at pos1;pos2;pos3
>   User with 14 is called Jill and works at pos134

Comment: Is there a way to replace the first `foreach` with a `while($row=blabla...)`?

Comment: @Hypn0tizeR of course; I don't see, from your sample data how you need it, but if you created a manual counter you could iterate with a while loop, also if you're reading in data from a database would work too.